# How to delete records that have expired in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to run this query in SQLite to delete any items that have "expired"

```
DELETE FROM availableLessons WHERE Date < DATE('now')
```

However it deletes every record in the database. The format used for the dates is `YYYY-MM-DD`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? `Date` is the column name that stores the dates. I have also tried adding a specific time, but nothing changed:

```
DELETE FROM availableLessons WHERE Date < DATE('2021-05-26')
```

Comment: Perhaps all rows have a date that is in the past.

Comment: No. I used dates that expire two months from now. I just inserted a single data that has "expired" to check whether the command works. Instead, it deletes everything.

Comment: Check for leading spaces in the column.

Comment: Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` query (`.schema availableLessons`) and a couple of example `INSERT` queries to try to reproduce your problem.